# jquery & PHP Ajax call returns empty-ish

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insertController.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success, you\'re data has been saved!');
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert('Failed, somthing went wrong, please try again!');
    }
});
```

The data is this:

```
name=James&email=test%40yahoo.com&7%3A00pm=on
```

but in the PHP end (insertController.php)

I try this:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

it returns

```
Array()
```

Is there something wrong with my data in my ajax call ?

Comment: your `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` doesn't match the data you are sending to php.

Comment: The `contentType` line sets the `Content-type` header of the *request* payload!  You are not sending JSON to your server, remove that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data`parameter accepts an Javascript object instead of a query string, so you need to use `$form.serializeArray()` instead of `serialize();`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insertController.php",
    data: $('form').serializeArray(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success, you\'re data has been saved!');
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert('Failed, somthing went wrong, please try again!');
    }
});
```